# AppRTC server setup

Tags: android, node.js, webrtc, stun, apprtcdemo

I think I'm going to cry...I looked everywhere and I still can't find the relevant pieces of info.

We created our own android WebRTC app using the appRTC demo app (https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo). It works fine when we use the https://appr.tc/ domain name.

We did not want to use Google GAE because it is not free. So we decided to use the AppRTC Node server (https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-node-server) and set it up on our own server. It works fine on our own https://our.web.site:3000 url. The online page looks exactly the same as the apppr.tc page. And we can connect using our webcams on web browsers.

But when we change the host in the appRTC android app then it basically says that our apprtc server does not return ICE server urls.

I'm lost. how does it work. Should the ICE servers be defined in the app or somewhere in the JS files of the AppRTC node server files?

Is the apprtc node server the equivalent of the appr.tc webpage? Is it STUN? TURN? ICE?

Also, can we just use a simple signalling server such as peer.js instead of the apprtc node server?

Thanks for your help.

Jennie

Answer (score 0):

No need for tears...

The repo you have picked up has no changes for the last 2 years, which means it is basically abandonware. It has no documentation either, which means that unless you are prepared to have a look at it yourself, you are going to struggle to get any help.

I use peerjs, and while it also has no activity from the original authors, a few people are using it, and there is at least some decent documentation. It also works pretty well. I have forked it myself, but mainly for diagnostic purposes, the original code is mostly untouched.

There are some demo projects for peerjs which you may be able to re-purpose to fit your situation.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response Mikkel. As you said, there is little documentation and I'm a beginner. 

So you used peer.js as a signalling server? 

I did not find any android peer client demo for webrtc (video/audio calls). 

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yes, I have set up peerjs-server, and included peer.js in my cordova android app, and it works well. Are you native android or hybrid?

Comment: Hi Mikkel, unfortunately we don't use Cordova. We develop native Android apps. For WebRTC, it seems that using Cordova would have been a lot more simple but we had to go native. Thanks